# Creating a switch based on entry handle

Tags: switch

I'm trying to create a switch statement for a single entry event template that has various entry fields associated with it (description, contact, location, etc.) from an Events Channel I have. Rather than using a bunch of IF's to display only those fields that have been populated, I'm trying to use a switch statement instead, but I can't get this to work when I based the switch on the 'entry.type." I'm trying to something like this, but it's not working. Any help would be appreciated!

```
{% switch entry.type %}
{% case 'contact' %}
    {{ entry.contact }}
{% case 'location' %}
    {{ entry.location }}
{% endswitch %}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a little unclear what you need to achieve here –

If your entries' [entry type](https://craftcms.com/features/entry-types) handles actually *are* `'contact'` and `'location'`, the above code should work; which means that you've got an error somewhere that isn't really possible to figure out based on your description – e.g. the entry type handle is actually `contacts`, and not `contact`, or something like that.

One thing you might try, is to simply print the `entry.type` variable in a template, to see if it contains what you expect it to contain:

```
{{ entry.type }}
```

On the other hand, if your issue is simply that some entries have a `contact` field populated and others have a `location` field populated, you can't really use a `{% switch %}` statement in any sensible manner for that – though a plain old `{% if %}` would do it:

```
{% if entry.contact %}
    {{ entry.contact }}
{% elseif entry.location %}
    {{ entry.location }}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Thanks, Mat! I was basically trying to do what you described, which is to use a switch statement rather than a bunch of IF statements. Good to know that wouldn't work. I was figuring using a switch was perhaps a better, less taxing way to set up all my fields, check to see if they're populated, and then have them print if the field is populated rathering than using a bunch of IFs. Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. In terms of _less taxin_, I really doubt you'll find any difference in performance in switch statements vs. regular if conditionals, one way or the other – switch statements can offer a more clear/readable syntax in some situations (and I don't think yours is a plausible use case for them), but that's about it :)